# woocommerce_form_field не передает в $_POST данные?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Пытаюсь передать из карточки товара мета данные в корзину которые пользователь выбрал
в селекте но в масив $_POST ничего не передается в чем может быть проблема?

```
`$options  = array( '' => __("Выбрать опцию") );
    foreach ( (array) explode( ',',$textarea_field ) as $model ) {
        $options[$model] = $model;
    }
    woocommerce_form_field( 'model', array(
        'type'     => 'select',
        'class'    => array('form-row-wide product-color'),
        'label'    => __('Модель'),
        'options'  => $options,
        'required' => true,
    ));

    echo '<br>';

});
var_dump(esc_attr($_POST["model"]));
add_action('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', function ( $cart_item_data, $product_id){
    $cart_item_data['attribute_model'] = esc_attr($_POST["model"]);        
    return $cart_item_data;
},10 ,2 );`
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что использовал не тот хук для вывода поля.

Нужно было:

```
woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button
```

, а я использовал:

```
 woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form
```